# Compass compilation error invalid charset

Tags: ruby, encoding, sass, compass

When inspecting the output of the sass file, I can see that `@charset "UTF-8";` is declared at the top ... I keep getting an error when using  `sass --watch file.scss:file.css` with this message:

```
/*
[exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Assetic\Exception\FilterException
[message] An error occurred while running:
&#039;/usr/local/bin/ruby&#039; &#039;/usr/local/bin/compass&#039; &#039;compile&#039; &#039;/private/var/tmp&#039; &#039;--boring&#039; &#039;--images-dir&#039; &#039;/www/symfony/app/../web/images&#039; &#039;--config&#039; &#039;/private/var/tmp/assetic_compassYuw3dl&#039; &#039;--sass-dir&#039; &#039;&#039; &#039;--css-dir&#039; &#039;&#039; &#039;/private/var/tmp/assetic_compassWIblXg.css&#039;

Output:
    error /private/var/tmp/assetic_compassWIblXg.css (Line 1: Invalid charset directive &#039;@charset&#039;: expected string.)
Compilation failed in 1 files.


Input:
@charset &quot;UTF-8&quot;;
```

I have made sure that all my files are UTF-8 encoded by setting it in my `.profile` and confirmed it with `$ locale`

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

I have also updated my ruby environment to `ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`

sass is running the latest version as well `Sass 3.4.9 (Selective Steve)`

as is Compass `Compass 1.0.1 (Polaris)`

I am running out of ideas. Does anybody know what else I can do to fix this?

Comment: Is it really escaping the html special chars like that?

Comment: Not sure, I don't think I've ever seen it do this.